# Zero-initialize a union in Rust

Tags: rust, union, unsafe

Is there a reasonable way to zero-initialize a `union` data type in Rust?

The approach mentioned by the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html#initialization-of-a-union) works well if the user initializes the largest field in the union, but doesn't work if a smaller field is set. For example, given a type:

```rs
union TypeFromFfi {
    small: u8,
    medium: u64,
    large: u128,
}
```

These don't seem to zero-initialize all of the union's memory:

```rs
let data = unsafe { TypeFromFfi { small: 0 } };
let data = unsafe { TypeFromFfi { medium: 0 } };
```

This seems to:

```rs
let data = unsafe { TypeFromFfi { large: 0 } };
```

This is as I expect, and I am hoping to avoid this approach because it requires the caller to remember the size of each field of the union.

Is there a general way to do zero-initialize a union? So far I have thought of:

```rs
let data = unsafe { std::mem::zeroed::<TypeFromFfi>() };
```

It seems to work, but is there something that I could be missing?

Could there be an issue with padding bytes from using [std::mem::zeroed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.zeroed.html)? I can't think of anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::mem::zeroed()` is the correct way. There is no problem with initializing padding bytes.

Do note however that [if zero is valid for none of the possible variants it is unclear yet whether zero-initializing the union is valid](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/73). If at any bit position zero is a valid pattern for at least one of the variants everything is fine.

Also note that your union probably has to be marked `#[repr(C)]`, otherwise you cannot rely on its layout (including the abovementioned zero validity).

Comment: [`MaybeUninit::zeroed().assume_init()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.zeroed) is another good approach.

Comment: @Aiden4 Longer than `std::mem::zeroed()`.

Comment: I would not advocate using `std::mem::zeroed`. It _might_ be ok in this instance but, in the general case, uninitialized and zeroed memory is an extremely tricky area, and it's just much easier to get it right with `MaybeUninit` - and in many cases, it's impossible to get it right with `std::mem::zeroed`.

Comment: I think the `MaybeUninit` has merit: a common pattern for FFI is initializing the variable with `let mut x = MaybeUninit::zeroed()` (or `uninit()` if you feel brave), then pass a pointer `x.as_mut_ptr()`to an FFI initialization function, and after checking for success, do `let x = x.assume_init()`. Also, for unsafe code, I consider it being longer to write to be a _feature_.

Comment: @PeterHall I definitely would not advocate for `std::mem::uninitialized()`, but `zeroed()` is fine, which is why it wasn't deprecated too. Of course, If I need a `MaybeUninit`, I would use `MaybeUninit::zeroed()`. But I have no problems with `MaybeUninit::zeroed().assume_init()` other than a slight preference :)